# Scala self types in pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, self-type

Given that I can create a trait that has self types and restricts the implementation and gives access to members like this:

```
trait A { def a:String }
trait B { def b:String }

trait C {
   self: A with B =>
   lazy val c:String = a+b
}
```

Why can't I bring that concept into a pattern match. I know below does not work, but is it just missing some syntactic sugar or are there limitations that prevents this?

```
case class AB( a:String, b:String ) extends A with B
val ab = AB("a","b")

ab match {
  case ab@(A & B) => ab.a + ab.b
}
```

What does work are these less elegant versions

```
ab match {
  case a:A => a match {
    case b:B => a.a + b.b
  }
}

def checkInstanceOf(obj:AnyRef) = 
  obj.isInstanceOf[A] && obj.isInstanceOf[B]
ab match {
  case ab if(checkInstanceOf(ab)) => ab.a + ab.b
}
```

My goal is to be able to write generic type driven behavior based on two or more traits being implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A normal typecheck for type `A with B` works:

```
ab match {
  case ab: A with B => ab.a + ab.b
}
```

Comment: Wat! I thought I tried that one my very first try, but apparently not.

Comment: Scala pattern matching is brilliant, I did not know you could do that. However when I think about it, Java 8 has now something similar